Joint distribution of exponential random variable conditional on their sum
Let $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ be independently exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$.
My question: what is the joint distribution of $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ conditional on $T = \sum^n_{i=1}y_i$ ?
We know that $T_n$ is marginally distributed as Gamma with shape $n$ and rate $\lambda$. So, assuming $y_i > 0$, we can write the joint conditional pdf as
\begin{align} f(y_1,...,y_n | T) &= \frac{f_\lambda(y_1,...y_n)}{f_\lambda(T)}   \\
                       &=\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda T}}{\lambda^{n}\frac{T^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-
\lambda T }}\\
&= \frac{(n-1)!}{T^{n-1}} 
\end{align}
However I can't seem to show this is a proper density? It doesn't seem to integrate to 1.
For example when $n = 2$, that would give us
$$ f(y_1, y_2 | T) = \frac{1}{T}$$
If we integrate that over $y_2$ from $0$ to $T$, we would get
$$ f(y_1 | T) = \int^T_{0} f(y_1, y_2 | T) d y_2 = \int^T_{0} \frac{1}{T} d y_2 = 1$$
Which is clearly wrong.

You might be thinking $\Gamma(a) = a!$ instead of $\Gamma(a)  = (a-1)!$ when writing the pdf of the Gamma distribution.
But also note that $f(y_1, y_2 | T)$ should be zero if $y_1 + y_2 \neq T$, so you might want to reconsider the bounds of integration when making sure the density integrates to 1.

Given $T=\sum^{n}_{i=1}Y_i=t$, the conditional distribution of the vector $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)'$ is a uniform distribution over the $n-1$ dimensional simplex $\left\{x \ge 0, \mathbf{1} ^Tx=t  \right \}=t\Delta^{n-1} $, that is,
$$\color{blue}{((Y_1,\dots,Y_n)' |T=t) \sim \mathcal U (t\Delta^{n-1})} \tag{1}$$
where $\Delta^{n-1}$ denotes the standard $n-1$ dimensional simplex $\{x \ge 0, \mathbf{1} ^Tx=1  \}$.

A quick proof:
This follows form the known fact that
$$\frac{(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)'}{Z_1+\dots+Z_n} \sim \mathcal U (\Delta^{n-1})$$
where $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ are iid $\text{Exp}(1)$ random variables, and noting that $\frac{1}{\lambda}\text{Exp}(1) \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, implying $\lambda(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)\sim (Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$.

Another proof: Given $T=t$, $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ does not have a joint conditional pdf considering $Y_n=t-\sum^{n}_{i=1}Y_i$, but $Y_1,\dots, Y_{n-1}$ have a pdf, obtained below.
The pdf of $T = \sum^n_{i=1}Y_i$  is given by
$$f(t)=\frac{\lambda^nt^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda t }\, t>0, \tag{2}$$
and the joint pdf of $Y_1,\dots,Y_{n-1},T$ can be obtained as follows:
$$f(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},t)=\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda t }, \, \sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i \le t, t>0. \tag{3}$$
Then, for $\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i \le t$ we obtain the following constant density:
$$\color{blue}{f(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1}|T=t)}=\frac{f(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},t)}{f(t)}= \frac{(n-1)!}{t^{n-1}}\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\text{vol} \left (t\Delta_{n-1} \right)}},$$
confirming (1).

If $Y_0,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent Gamma rv with the same scale parameter $\lambda$ and shape parameters $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ and if $T=Y_0+\cdots+Y_n$ then $\frac{1}{T}(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is Dirichlet distributed with density on $u_i>0$ for all $i=0,\ldots,n$ (with the convention $u_0=1-u_1-\ldots-u_n$)
$$\frac{\Gamma(a_0+\cdots+a_n)}{\Gamma(a_0)\ldots \Gamma(a_n)}u_0^{a_0-1}u_1^{a_1-1}\ldots y_n^{a_n-1}.$$ From this you get the conditional law of $Y_0,\ldots,Y_n$ knowing $T$.

The element $f(y_1,...,y_n|T)$ is not a continuous density, as the distribution of $(Y_1, ..., Y_N)$ conditional on their sum $T$ is a degenerate distribution.
Instead, we can study the density of $f(y_1, ..., y_{n-1} | T$), for which we have, assuming $y_i > 0$,
\begin{align} f(y_1,...,y_{n-1} | T) &= \frac{f_\lambda(y_1,...y_{n-1}, T)}{f_\lambda(T)} I\left[\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i < T\right]  \\
                       &= \frac{f_\lambda(y_1,...y_n)}{f_\lambda(T)}I\left[\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i < T\right] \\  
                       &=\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda T}}{\lambda^{n}\frac{T^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-
\lambda T }}I\left[\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i < T\right]\\
&= \frac{(n-1)!}{T^{n-1}}I\left[\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}y_i < T\right]
\end{align}
In the case $n = 2$, this simplifies to
$f(y_1 | T) = \frac{1}{T} I[ y_1 < T]$
Which is Uniform$(0, T)$ and  integrates to 1 as shown in the original post.
